# Refresh best_in_place dropdown in rails4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, best-in-place

I have a best_in_place dropdown to show all authors, and it has an option to add new value, when addnew value clicked,a textbox (best_in_place) appears and can add value,i need the the newly added value in that dropdown, from now the value appears only on refesh..any ideas..? thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `best_in_place` uses only the `select` options you rendered on the sever. It doesn't support updating the collection later.

Comment: Good luck :-D I didn't see anything simple, post back if you figure it out.

Comment: thnks bro, lemme go thru partials  and urls ..sure i will post wen i gt one.